# Mismatch in modules installed with Python

Tags: python, homebrew

I am a bit of a Python newbie, and am struggling with what seems like a simple task.

I have installed Python using Homebrew on my Mac.  When I run `which python` it returns `/usr/local/bin/python` and when I run `ls -al /usr/local/bin/python` I can see that python is symlinked as follows `/usr/local/bin/python -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.1/bin/python`, indicating that Homebrew's version of Python is installed.

Now when I install the boto module, I did so as follows:
`easy_install boto` and it showed me that the module is installed into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto-2.2.2-py2.7.egg`

The odd thing is that when I do the following, I am told the boto module does not exist.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Aug 31 2011, 23:21:36)
>>> import boto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boto
```

Why is that module not available?  It's almost like Homebrew is installing modules into the standard library folder, but is not linking back to that directory when searching for installed modules.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`easy_install` is a script which calls a certain version of python. It must be pointing to the wrong python in your case.

```
% which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
```

Notice that in my example, `easy_install` is calling `/usr/bin/python`:

```
% head -n1 /usr/bin/easy_install
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Change the first line to point to `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Alternatively, your installation of `Homebrew` might come with its own `easy_install`. In that case, just find `Homebrew`'s easy_install and call that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also invoke the specific version of easy_install you want to use.  For example, if you want to use the python 3 version of easy_install you got via homebrew, it is in /usr/local/share/python3.